# In a Chrome Extension, how do I change the full background color of a popup window?

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have a new tab Google Chrome Extension. In the bottom-left, I have a settings menu that kind of pops up a little frame when you click on it. However, the background color for the popup is white and I would like to change it to completely black. How do I change the full frame background color? Here is my code:    [Image of my code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SIkt.png)

```html
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-0 settingscontainer">
          <i class="fa fa-cog settingsbtn fa-2x" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-html="true"
            data-content="" >
          </i>
           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a sample with regard to changing the colors of background page which can be applied to your `popup.html`. This is found in [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

popup.html will be rendered inside the popup window that's created in response to a user's click on the browser action. It's a standard HTML file, just like you're used to from web development, giving you more or less free reign over what the popup displays.

And this is snippet from the sample:

```
/**
 * Change the background color of the current page.
 *
 * @param {string} color The new background color.
 */
function changeBackgroundColor(color) {
  var script = 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="' + color + '";';
  // See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript.
  // chrome.tabs.executeScript allows us to programmatically inject JavaScript
  // into a page. Since we omit the optional first argument "tabId", the script
  // is inserted into the active tab of the current window, which serves as the
  // default.
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: script
  });
}
```

Comment: he asked how to change the popup background color not the page's background color